# Pyspark - Joins _ duplicate columns

Tags: dataframe, join, pyspark, duplicates

I have 3 dataframes.
each of them have columns which look like below:

[image]

I am using below code to join them:

```
cond = [df1.col8_S1 == df2.col8_S1, df1.col8_S2 == df2.col8_S2]
df = df1.join(df2,cond,how ='inner').drop('df1.col8_S1','df1.col8_S2')
cond = [df.col8_S1 == df3.col8_S1, df.col8_S2 == df3.col8_S2]
df4 = df.join(df3,cond,how ='inner').drop('df3.col8_S1','df3.col8_S2')
```

I am writing the dataframe onto csv file; however since they have same columns from col1 to col7, the write fails due to duplicate columns. How to I drop the duplicate columns without specifying their names.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the column names for join, instead of explicitly using equal op.

```
cond = ['col8_S1', 'col8_S2']
df = df1.join(df2, cond, how ='inner')
cond = ['col8_S1', 'col8_S2']
df4 = df.join(df3, cond, how ='inner')
```

Comment: it still doesnt eliminate the duplicate columns